# How do I copy a sculpt mask from one object to another?

Tags: sculpting, masking

I made a mistake while sculpting by making a mask and sculpting only a quarter of my object, thinking I could mirror the object after to create the whole thing.
[image]

But when I mirror the object, there are creases and holees, and generally the quarters just don't match up well.
[image]

I'd like to copy over just the mask I painted to a new object, and then hopefully use the symmetrize option to salvage my sculpt. Is there any way of doing so, or any other way of salvaging this sculpt? Or do I just have to start over again?